# Scrapy: Pass variable from Middleware to Spider itself

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware

I am trying to capture the raw request payload and request headers for the purpose of tracking inside my database. I know about the `response.request.headers` but that is the returned request headers.

Would it be possible to create a middleware that captures the request.headers and payload (body) and send that to the spider as a meta tag or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it (granted without the middleware):

- Store the scrapy.Request() into a variable e.g. `req`
- Store `req.headers.to_unicode_dict()` into `self.req_headers`
- Store `req.body` into `self.req_body`
- Execute `yield req` to send the request